# Facebook authentication on S4 vs Nexus

Tags: android, facebook, galaxy

I'm trying to allow my android app to post to facebook, a user selects a share option and if the app can retrieve the login data from the original facebook app it logs in and the user can share a message, otherwise they can provide the details. I've got the code working perfectly on a galaxy nexus running android 4.2.1 and emulator (4.2.2), but on my galaxy S4 (4.4.2) it doesn't work, it asks the user to access facebook profile and friends list. After you click accept it just goes back to the login screen. I expect it has something to do with the session not being passed back after login. 
Why does The exact same code work on a nexus and emulator but not a S4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All developers needs to be registered with a Facebook Developers account. To add a developer go to your [Applications Page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), and in the Roles section click Edit Roles. Now you can add people who will be using your application during the development phase including Admin, Developers and Testers.